# Multiple CMake Projects in one CMakeLists.txt

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build, cmake

I want to have two projects that build off the same source files, with the second one just having a small subset, and a few different defines and build flags.

When I try something like this:

```
SET (this_target PROJECT1)
PROJECT(${this_target})

...

ADD_EXECUTABLE(#{this_target} ...)

SET (this_target PROJECT2)
PROJECT(${this_target})

...

add_definitions (-DMYDEFINE)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( ${this_target} -myflag )

ADD_EXECUTABLE(#{this_target} ...)
```

It ends up creating two projects, with seemingly the proper source files and the like, but for some reason, at least in Visual Studio 2010, both projects seem to get MYDEFINE defined and myflag in the linker flags.

I'm not sure why it seems to work for files, but not flags.

Comment: You are not supposed to have more than 1 PROJECT() in a single CMakeList.txt file.

Comment: Is there anything I can do other than create a separate nearly empty directory with just a CMakeLists.txt file?

Comment: Normally I put each target in its own folder however you can just remove the second PROJECT() and change the name of the variable used in the second target to be something other than this_target.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, you must use different names for your executables
If you want to add specific definitions to your targets, you may use set_target_properties, so each target will have their own properties (for example, compile definitions).

```
# compile and link first app
add_executable(prg1 ${CommonSources} ${Prg1SpecificSources})
target_link_libraries(prg1 lib1 lib2 lib3)

#set target-specific options
set_target_properties(prg1 PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "FOO=BAR1")

#...

# compile and link second app
add_executable(prg2 ${CommonSources} ${Prg2SpecificSources})
target_link_libraries(prg2 lib1 lib2 lib3)
#set target-specific options
set_target_properties(prg1 PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "FOO=BAR2")
```

If you want to override linking flags, you may use **set_target_properties** with **LINK_FLAGS**

Answer (score 1):

I've found that putting multiple targets in one CMakeLists.txt causes intermittent build failure on Visual Studio 2010, due to colliding accesses to generate.stamp (though I can't rule out that I'm doing something wrong). Thus, you may have to put the targets in different CMakeLists.txt files, or find some other workaround.